# Google maps event - get parent of clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have function with which I'm making new object 'claster'. In every claster is marker from google maps API. I want to click on this marker and get access to claster.icons[]. I'm binding click event in my function declaration. How to do it?

**CODE**

```
function newClaster(_center){
        this.centerIco = _center;
        this.center = this.centerIco.getPosition();
        this.icons = [];
        this.icons.push(this.centerIco);
        this.addIcon = function(_icon){this.icons.push(_icon)};
        this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position : this.center,
            icon : {
                url : 'map/circle.png',
                scaledSize : new google.maps.Size(40,40),
                size : new google.maps.Size(40,40),
            },
            map:map,
        });
        this.setCenter = function(ctr){
            this.centerIco = ctr;
            this.center = ctr.getPosition();
        }
        this.findCenter = function(){
            this.centerIco = this.icons[parseInt((this.icons.length)%2)];
            this.center = this.centerIco.getPosition();
        }

        google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker, 'click', function(){
            this.icons 
        });
    }
```

I'm binding click on marker.

Answer (score 0):

add a function and send the marker to it on click, then you can get the icons by accessing the marker object:

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker, 'click', getIcons(this));

function getIcons(marker){
  console.log(marker.icons);
}
```

Comment: Then i'm getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined.